# how usefull using browser specific css like -webkit- -moz-

Tags: html, css

How this browser specific css used?

I have this:

```
.example {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s ;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s ;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s
}
```

All have same value `all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s`

Should i use all three of them, or just one like this?

```
.example {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s ;
}
```

Previous value for this transition css is by default.

Is this browser specific css used if i want specific styling for certain browser only, or is it a requirement that have to be used even if the value is same?

Comment: http://css-snippets.com/browser-prefix/. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401830/do-we-have-to-use-non-standard-browser-specific-css-vendor-prefixes-anymore possible duplicate

Comment: You only need -webkit prefix. -moz is not needed anymore. http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Answer (score 0):

```
.example {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s ;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s ;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s
}
```

This will work for the most browsers.

**AND**

```
.example {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s ;
}
```

This will work for not more than 2 browsers

**See this guide**: http://caniuse.com/