# CSS - why to add -webkit and so on to transitions

Tags: css

I have a small question, I am new to CSS and I have pretty stupid question. Why everybody add -webkit for Chrome and Safari, -moz for Mozzila Firefox and so on, I used just "transition:" and value and it worked on Mozzila, Chrome and Opera too. So what's the reason to add it?
Thanks.

Comment: To support older browsers. See more here: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition. They are native in the most recent browsers, but less support the further you go back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have to use non-standard/browser specific CSS vendor prefixes anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401830/do-we-have-to-use-non-standard-browser-specific-css-vendor-prefixes-anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's for older versions of those browsers which only respond to the prefixed settings and are still installed on some computers.

Answer (score 0):

Web world changes a lot, and before there was official support for CSS3 (such as the transition you are using), there were fallbacks, and shims to add these features specific to browsers.

The reason people would still use `-moz` & `-webkit` is to include support for older browsers. You should read up on the pains of doing this especially for internet explorer. So if you don't want to leave your ie9 customers behind, you should try and include appropriate CSS for them. `transition` isn't going to cut it for these browsers.